# Grabbing invoice pdf file through API

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, rest-api, magento-2.2.5, invoice-pdf

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction on how to generate an invoice pdf for an already invoiced order through the rest api.

It looks like in the admin, Magento is creating it on the fly when you press print PDF.

Looking for a way to generate this invoice pdf from the API and save it to the server so that I can send it to another server.

Magento 2.2.5

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer the below link for getting right guidance  to generate Invoice PDF via REST API.

https://dev98.de/2017/09/10/get-pdf-files-by-magento-webapi/

Comment: I tried this link but getting only invoice response. Not getting pdf files and pdf link